# How do I get to the main method from another method c#

Tags: c#

Obliviously an amateur question for some of yous but I can figure it out. I know how to go to other methods in my program because they don't need any arguments. What are the arguments I put inside the parenthesis when trying to go back to the main method?

```
static void writeToFile(string filename, Customer obj, int pos, int size)
{

    FileStream fout;

    BinaryWriter bw;

    //create a file stream object

    fout = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);

    //create a binary writer object
    bw = new BinaryWriter(fout);

    //set file position where to write data
    fout.Position = pos * size;
    //write data
    bw.Write(obj.CustomerNo);
    bw.Write(obj.Surname);
    bw.Write(obj.Forename);
    bw.Write(obj.Street);
    bw.Write(obj.Town);
    bw.Write(obj.DOB);
    //close objects
    bw.Close();
    fout.Close();

    Main(); // what goes inside these parenthesis
}
```

Comment: `ClassName.Main();`???

Comment: You don't.  The main method executes at the beginning of your program run, and terminates at the end of your program run.  If you want to go somewhere else and then come back to main, make a call to a method.

Comment: I'm surprised. You've asked a few C# questions and you don't know this?

Comment: If you're calling that method from your `Main()` method, just allow it to return.  You don't need that `Main()` call.

Comment: Methods is new to me still trying to get my head round it. no joy with ClassName.Main(); 'the name classname.main(); does not exsit in the current context

Comment: You don't have to call `Main`.  Just remove that line of code from your method.  Your program will return to the place where you called `writeToFile()`, and continue execution with the line of code following the `writeToFile()` call.

Comment: There is no code left to execute in the method that called write to file. Basically the menu is in the main method and i'm looking to get back there after the writeToFile method is finished, because there is nothing else left to execute and the program just exits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main()
{
    // do some stuff
    // ...
    WriteToFile(filename, obj, pos, size);
    // ...
    // Program execution automatically returns here after WriteToFile is done.
    // do some more stuff
    // ...
    // Program ends.  Thank you for playing.
}

static void WriteToFile(string filename, Customer obj, int pos, int size)
{
    // yada yada
    // No need for a Main() call
    // We're done, and about to leave the WriteToFile method.  See you later.
}
```

Comment: In my main, I go to a method call cust, then i then go to another method called addCust and then at the bottom of this method is writeToFile(@"..\..\..\Files\Customers.txt", _cust, pos, Record_Size); // end of method then this takes me to my WriteToFile method... So when it goes back it has nothing left to do so exits.. hope you can understand now why i cant get back to main and why there is a need to call it.

Comment: Then just substitute `cust` for `WriteToFile` in my example, and it still works.  Method calls can be nested; `writeToFile` will return to `addCust`, which will return to `cust`, which will return to `Main()`.

Comment: Sorry I cant understand that.  Is there a way to call the main if you wanted say you wanted to?

Comment: You don't call main.  The operating system does.  That's all.  If you just allow your methods to return naturally, everything will be fine.